# Some unexpected thing with my shell script

Tags: shell

This script is used for detecting USB drive input any copy some log files to USB.
on line 47, 
`cp "/home/root/io/log/${end}.txt" "${USB}/log" && let sfile++ || let err3=1`
 three commands are all executed, whether the cp command is succeed or not. And if I swap this line with line 49
 `cp "/home/root/io/log/${begin}.txt" "${USB}/log" && let sfile++ || let err3=1`
, only the upper line of codes didn't work as expected.

```
echo $USB > /dev/null
echo $FILE > /dev/null
echo $begin > /dev/null
echo $end > /dev/null
echo $destfile > /dev/null
echo $tmp > /dev/null
echo $err > /dev/null
echo $sfile > /dev/null
echo $DATE > /dev/null

echo 84 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio84/direction


while true
do
    USB=""
    FILE=""
    begin=""
    end=""
    destfile=""
    DATE=""
    let err1=0
    let err2=0
    let err3=0
    let err4=0
    let err=0
    let sfile=0
    ls /dev/sda1 > /dev/null 2>&1 || rm -rf /media/sda1
    ls /media/sda1 > /dev/null 2>&1 && USB="/media/sda1"
    if [[ "$USB" != "" ]]; then
        ls $USB | grep 'cp.txt' > /dev/null && FILE="cp.txt"
        if [[ "$FILE" != "" ]]; then

            ls "${USB}/log" > /dev/null 2>&1 && rm -rf "${USB}/log"
            mkdir "${USB}/log" && echo 0 >> /dev/null || let err1=1

            begin=$(cat "${USB}/${FILE}" | cut -d 'd' -f 2)
            end=$(cat "${USB}/${FILE}" | cut -d 'd' -f 3)

            cp "/home/root/io/log/${end}.txt" "${USB}/log" && let sfile++ || let err3=1

            cp "/home/root/io/log/${begin}.txt" "${USB}/log" && let sfile++ || let err2=1

            destfile=$(ls /home/root/io/log)
            destfile=${destfile#*${begin}.txt}
            destfile=${destfile%${end}.txt*}
            echo $destfile

            while [[ "$(echo $destfile | cut -d ' ' -f 1)" != "" ]]; do
                tmp=""
                tmp=$(echo $destfile | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
                destfile=${destfile#*$tmp}
                cp "/home/root/io/log/${tmp}" "${USB}/log" && let sfile++ || let err4=1
            done
            DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)
            LOG="${DATE} Requested: from-${begin} to-${end}. Succeed:${sfile} err1:${err1}err2:${err2}err3:${err3}err4:${err4}"
            echo $LOG >> /home/root/io/cplog/cplog.txt
            echo $LOG >> /media/sda1/cplog.txt
            if [[ err -eq 0 ]]; then
                echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio84/value
                sleep 1
                echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio84/value
            else
                for (( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )); do
                    echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio84/value
                    sleep 0.05
                    echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio84/value
                    sleep 0.05
                done
            fi
            umount "${USB}"
        fi
    fi
    sleep 2
done
```

Comment: Also can anyone provide me some suggestions with my code? I'm new to the shell script and my coding habit is mostly affected by c++ coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using bash, but unless you stick with POSIX-compatibility, always indicate the shell you are using. Assuming bash, if you have a command sequence `X && Y || Z`, and if X returns a non-zero exit status, Y won't be executed.

Aside from this, you do have a logical flaw in your script. Note that `let` also sets an exit status. The exit status is 1 if the value of the expression to be evaluated, is 0, and the exit status is 0 otherwise. Now regarding your `let sfile++`, the value of the expression is the value which `sfile` had **before** incrementing.

In the first iteration of your loop, `sfile` is zero. Assuming that cp returns exit code 0, `sfile` will be incremented, the `let` command returns exit code **1**, and the `let err4=1` will also be executed.

In the subsequent iterations, this won't happen anymore, because `let sfile++` returns exit code **0**.

My advice is to not be too fancy with command sequences mixing && and ||. In this case, a simple `if` would be the better choice:

```
if cp ...
then
  let ...
else
  let
fi
```

Comment: i changed the long command into if statement, and it works as I expected. Thanks a lot